# How to perform Windows authentication from apache

Tags: apache, .net-core, windows-authentication

I need some help to configure Windows authentication from Apache. What I've done so far is:

1. I create a new simple project (the default) of .net core from visual studio.
2. I add this line: `services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();` to the Startup.ConfigureServices.
3. Then I add this line: `app.UseAuthentication();` to `Startup.Configure`.
4. if I run the project from the IIS, I was able to see the user.
5. if I run the project from Apache (CentOS), I get this:

   ```
   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
   ```
6. The machine is joined to the domain.

I'm sure that there is other thing I need to configure (SPN, Service account) but I don't now the order and the steps.